# Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^(\d{1}+(K|k){0,1}){0,1}$/: Nothing to repeat

Tags: javascript

I have make this at aspx to run but

```
            function setAction()
        {           
            var idCheck = /^\w*$/;
            var bandwidthCheck = /^{\d{1}+(K|k){0,1}}{0,1}$/;

            if (document.video.eventID.value == '' || !idCheck.test(document.video.eventID.value)){
                alert("Please enter a valid Event ID");
                return false;               
            }
            else if (document.video.streamID.value == '' || !idCheck.test(document.video.streamID.value)){
                alert("Please enter a valid Stream ID");
                return false;               
            }
            else if (!bandwidthCheck.test(document.video.bandwidth.value)){
                alert("Please enter a valid Bandwidth");
                return false;               
            }               
            else if (document.video.file.value == ''){
                alert("Please select a media file");
                return false;
            }

        }
```

Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^(\d{1}+(K|k){0,1}){0,1}$/: Nothing to repeat
Need Help

Comment: If you use {1} you should not use + after, the proper regex would be `/^(\d{1}(K|k){0,1}){0,1}$/` or `/^(\d+(K|k){0,1}){0,1}$/` or if you want to match literal + then you should escape it with `\+`

Comment: Also your bandwidthCheck variable have `^{ ... }` if you want literal { } you also need to escape those with `^\{ ... \}`